# Mean of list of matrices by element

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices:

```
 .list <- list(matrix(1:25, ncol = 5), matrix(11:35, ncol = 5))
```

I would like to use the `Reduce` method to find the element-by-element means of the matrices in the list.

In other words, I am looking for the following result:

```
 res = matrix(6:30, ncol = 5)
```

I tried the following:

```
 res = Reduce(mean, .list)
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in mean.default(init, x[[i]]) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Note that an element of a matrix can be `NA`.

Answer (score 6):

I just realized that this could be achieved the following way (using the `Reduce` function):

```
 tmp = Reduce('+', .list)
 result = tmp/length(.list)
```

Comment: I don't think that will account for `NA`, unless the result should be `NA` in that case?

Comment: To handle the `NA`, you'd need to apply a function that did `'+'()` after removing the `NA` elements.

Comment: Just add `lapply(list_, function(x) x * !is.na(x))` before doing `Reduce(..)` maybe..

Comment: @Arun Indeed, but that seems an awful lot of effort to go to for a simple array operation? Why does this *have* to be done via `Reduce()`? The only downside to storing the matrices as an array is if there are more than `2^31 - 1` total elements over the matrices in the list. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Yes, I see your point. If the data has no NAs, I'd prefer the `Reduce` solution as it simply turns out faster, as long as the matrices are not *really huge*.

Comment: @Arun It is only faster (admittedly in my simple tests) if I include the conversion to array step in my `rowMeans()` version. `rowMeans()` and `Reduce()` versions seems to be comparable in execution time for 1000 repeats of the problem posed by the OP.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, wow, then that's great. To be frank, I've not done the benchmarks myself for this sort of problem. But my idea of `Reduce` being faster comes from looking at some benchmarks here on SO at some point in time :).

Answer (score 5):

This is probably easier to solve via an array, rather than a list, as R has some inbuilt, vectorised approaches to this problem.

To get an array from `.list`, unlist it and supply the relevant dimensions (which could be automated by looking up the `dim()` of `.list[[1]]` and `length(.list)`:

```
arr <- array(unlist(.list), dim = c(5,5,2))
```

Then, the desired result is obtained via `rowMeans()` (yes, really!)

```
rowMeans(arr, dim = 2)

R> rowMeans(arr, dim = 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6   11   16   21   26
[2,]    7   12   17   22   27
[3,]    8   13   18   23   28
[4,]    9   14   19   24   29
[5,]   10   15   20   25   30
```

The `na.rm` argument handles the `NA` case too:

```
R> rowMeans(arr, dim = 2, na.rm = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6   11   16   21   26
[2,]    7   12   17   22   27
[3,]    8   13   18   23   28
[4,]    9   14   19   24   29
[5,]   10   15   20   25   30
```

A slower way is to use `apply()`, which may be more instructive as to what `rowMeans()` is doing:

```
R> apply(arr, 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6   11   16   21   26
[2,]    7   12   17   22   27
[3,]    8   13   18   23   28
[4,]    9   14   19   24   29
[5,]   10   15   20   25   30
```

i.e applying the mean function, grouping the data by the row and column dimensions. Think of the array as a box, with the height of the box being the third dimension. This box consists of little cubes, like a rubic cube. We want the mean of the little cubes stacked up above each row and column combination; the mean of the little cubes stacked above (1,1), and so on. This is what the `apply()` and `rowMeans()` functions do for you, if you treat the multiple matrices in a list as an array.

Comment: +1 this is much cleaner.

Comment: +1 Also of relevance: `?simplify2array`.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the pointer; I'd totally forgotten that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `mapply`.

```
matrix(do.call(mapply, c(function(...) mean(unlist(list(...))), .list)), ncol=5)
```

As a side note, `.list` isn't the best way to use a keyword as a variable name. In R, the period prefix means something like "meta-variable", and these variables won't show up when you call `ls()`. You could do `list.` or the easier to read `list_`.

Comment: Well, your answer is great, thank you. However, I found a way of doing it using `Reduce` (please see my posted own answer). It seems to be correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, +1. Excuse me why I eat my words ...